# Как узнать название приложения, если известно название процесса принадлежащее этому приложению?

Tags: java, android

Есть название процесса например `com.android.vending`, могу ли я как то получить название приложения которому принадлежит этот процесс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, название процесса это пакет приложения. Исходя из этого, можно вбить в гугл вот это

> [android get app name by package](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android%20get%20app%20name%20by%20package)

сходить по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841353/3212712)

и получить имя приложения через PackageManager, получив ApplicationInfo из него по пакету так:

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

для любого не текущего приложения замените `this.getPackageName()` на `"com.android.vending"`